# How to set the Maven profiles in Visual Studio Code?

Tags: visual-studio-code, maven-profiles

I couldn't find the way to set the current Maven profiles in Visual Studio Code in order to compile my project using specific profiles, does someone know how to do that?

Answer (score 4):

Currently you can add "-PprofileName" to entry "maven.executable.options" in settings, e.g. in workspace settings. Then it appends the string when constructing commands.

e.g: maven.executable.options": "-Pdev"

[github vscode maven plugin](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode-maven/issues/117)