# How do I specify the maven profile name to use when debugging a spring boot app with Visual Studio Code?

Tags: maven, debugging, visual-studio-code, vscode-debugger, maven-profiles

This might very well be a duplicate of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54550365/how-to-set-the-maven-profiles-in-visual-studio-code), but the answer there doesn't work.

In my POM file, I have several profiles defined similar to this:

```
<profiles>
    <profile>
        <id>dev</id>
        <properties> 
            <activated-profile>dev</activated-profile>
        </properties>
    </profile>
    ...
</profiles>
```

`activated-profile` is a property used in the `application.properties` file to tell spring boot what profile to use:

```
...
spring.profiles.active=@activated-profile@
...
```

If I run `mvn clean install package spring-boot:repackage -Pdev` in a cmd prompt, I can see in the cmd prompt window `The following profiles are active: dev`, indicating that the correct profile is active.

If I try to launch and debug the app from Visual Studio Code, in the terminal I get `The following profiles are active: @activated-profile@`.

I tried setting args in `launch.json`:

```
{
    ...
    "args": ["activated-profile=dev"],
    "vmArgs": ["Dactivated-profile=dev"],
    ...
}
```

I also tried setting a custom environment variable for maven in `settings.json`, as well as the answer in the question which you will undoudbtedly tell me I duplicated:

```
{
    ...
    "maven.executable.options": "-Pdev",    
    "maven.terminal.customEnv": [{
        "environmentVariable": "activated-profile", "value": "dev" 
    }],
    ...
}
```

I also tried prepending `activated-profile` with `-`, `--`, `D`, `-D` or `--D`, as well as renaming `activated-profile` to `activatedprofile` in case the hyphen messes things up somehow.

Nothing works.

The only way I can get VS Code to start debugging is if I specify the default profile in the POM file:

```
<activation>
    <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
</activation>
```

However, this is not ideal because everytime I want to build the app with a different profile, I have to remove that piece of code since maven, in it's infinite wisdom, decided not to override that profile if I specify it in the command line, rendering `-Pdev` or `-Pint` useless. In other words, if I want Jenkins to be able do build the app, the `activeByDefault` XML should not exist in the POM.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following solution assumes you already have the ***Java Extension Pack*** installed.

If not, please proceed with the installation then continue reading ([Link to install Java Extension Pack](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=vscjava.vscode-java-pack))

In your ***launch.json*** configuration (***Run -> Open Configurations***) you need to use ***vmArgs*** as follows:

```
{
"version": "0.2.0",
"configurations": [
    {
        "type": "java",
        "name": "Launch MyApp",
        "request": "launch",
        "mainClass": "com.example.MySpringApplication",
        "projectName": "myproject",
        "vmArgs": " -Dspring.profiles.active=dev"
    }
 ]
}
```

You can (of course) use multiple profiles at the same time for example if you already have separated your Spring security config into a different file (for instance ***devsec-application.yaml***):

```
"vmArgs": " -Dspring.profiles.active=dev,devsec"
```

Comment: I could've sworn I tried that. I guess I didn't. Thanks!

Comment: Yes but what you have specifed is spring profiles, but lets say if I have a "MAVEN PROFILE" where i have included or excluded some dependencies, will this still work? Because, isnt it to late to alter a maven profile post build is completed?

Comment: Well I tried this, this indeed doesnt active a certain maven profile something like when you do mvn clean install -Pdev. This is just a way of activating spring profile instead of a "MAVEN PROFILE"

Comment: @DeekshithAnand, did you figure out how to add a maven profile?

Comment: Anyone figured out adding a maven profile in vs code?